# Trying to access a SQL Server database to display a single row in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, ado.net

I'm trying to access a SQL Server database and display a single row using C#. I'm having trouble figuring out how to properly do this. Please help. Thank you.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost \\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=MMABooks;" + "Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    string selectStatement = "SELECT ProductCode " + "FROM Products " + "WHERE ProductCode = @ProductCode";
    SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, connection);

    selectCommand.Parameters.Add("@ProductCode");

    connection.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);

    reader.Read();

    txtDisplay.Text = reader["ProductCode"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: So what is the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are passing the parameter productcode to the query and returning the same as result. Please make the scenario clear. if you need to pass the product code and get the same from table, what you can do is :

```
 public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost \\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=MMABooks;" + "Integrated Security=True";
    Object returnValue;
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    string selectStatement = "SELECT Top 1 ProductCode " + "FROM Products " + "WHERE ProductCode = @ProductCode";
    SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, connection);

    selectCommand.Commandtype = CommandType.Text;
    connection.Open();

    returnValue = selectCommand.ExecuteScalar();
    connection.Close();
    txtDisplay.Text = returnValue.ToString();

}
```

Comment: I tried your piece of code and it's saying Commandtype could not be found, Am I missing a using statement to access it? Im using using sql.Data.SqlClient.

Comment: I figured out it was just a typo with the commandtype, but now i'm getting this error Must declare the scalar variable "@ProductCode". When I try to debug it.

Comment: try using this too :using System.Data; using System.Data.SqlClient; either you need to pass the product variable to the function and use the variable name in the inline select query, or just assign value for the @product code

Comment: It worked, When I assigned selectCommand.Parameter,AddWithValue () with a string which was telling it when row I wanted. Thank you guys.

Comment: Just validate the answers given by all if its worked for you.It may help others who all try this.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I tried to correct some issues in your code:

There was a strange space in connection string.

You don't need to concatenate two string, just write one string and it's ok.

You didn't set the value of the parameter. I used the AddWithValue method.

You didn't close the reader and the connection after reading it.

```
 string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost\\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=MMABooks;Integrated Security=True";
 SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

 string selectStatement = "SELECT ProductCode FROM Products WHERE ProductCode = @ProductCode";
 SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, connection);

 selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", "XYZ");//Or whatever your parameter value is
 connection.Open();

 SqlDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);

 reader.Read();

 txtDisplay.Text = reader["ProductCode"].ToString();

 reader.Close();

 connection.Close();
```

Anyway, the logic in the code doesn't make sense at all. You make a query using a parameter as a key and then you display the parameter value. This makes the query totally useless!

Comment: I'm confused on how to use the AddWithvalue method correctly, I know @productCode is pointing to the row i'm trying to access, but what am i suppose to put as a parameter value. I basically just want the productcode to display in txtDisplay.Text.

Comment: Have you got a product code value before performing the query? Or you want to display only the first line? It makes no sense to use a parameter in a query and then display it as the only outupt

Comment: Lets say one of the product code value reads A3CS so that's the row I want it to display. Could I just create a string for A3CS and place that as a parameter value, So it knows which one I'm asking for?

Comment: Yes, but maybe you want to display some other information in the texbox. Believe me, it really doesn't make much sense to make a query and then display just the parameter.

Comment: Okay. Let me try that. Thanks. But will the SQL database know I'm trying to use a string to describe with row i'm trying to point too?

Comment: It worked, When I assigned selectCommand.Parameter,AddWithValue () with a string which was telling it when row I wanted. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

To assign the variable you can use this code : Please make sure the value of productcode in the database. here i gave the datatype as varchar , if its not just replace the datatype with varchar.

```
public Form1(string productCodevalue){
InitializeComponent();

string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost \\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=MMABooks;" + "Integrated Security=True";
Object returnValue;
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

string selectStatement = "SELECT Top 1 ProductCode " + "FROM Products " + "WHERE ProductCode = @ProductCode";
SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, connection);

selectCommand.Commandtype = CommandType.Text;
selectCommand.Parameters.Add("ProductCode", SqlType.VarChar).Value = productCodevalue;
connection.Open();

returnValue = selectCommand.ExecuteScalar();
connection.Close();
txtDisplay.Text = returnValue.ToString();
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

```
public Form1(string productCodevalue){
InitializeComponent();

string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost \\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=MMABooks;" + "Integrated Security=True";
Object returnValue;
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

string selectStatement = "SELECT Top 1 ProductCode " + "FROM Products " + "WHERE ProductCode = @ProductCode";
SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, connection);

selectCommand.Commandtype = CommandType.Text;
selectCommand.Parameters.Add("ProductCode", SqlType.VarChar).Value = productCodevalue;
connection.Open();

returnValue = selectCommand.ExecuteScalar();
connection.Close();
txtDisplay.Text = returnValue.ToString();}`
```

Comment: Make sure the datatype of product code in the database is varchar. here in code i gave its as varchar if not just replace the datatype with varchar and try this

Answer (score 0):

```
 string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost\\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=MMABooks;" + "Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);


        string selectStatement = "SELECT ProductCode " + "FROM Products " + "WHERE ProductCode = @ProductCode";
        SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, connection);

        string code = "DB1R";

        selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", code);  //productcode points to the column, and code points the row
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);

        reader.Read();

        txtDisplay.Text = reader["ProductCode"].ToString();

        connection.Close();
```